# Crystal Reports: How do I repeat a constant number of rows / headers on each new page in a cross-tab?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crosstab

I have some data that I've staged in my database as such:

```
RowHeader    ColumnHeader    Value
Row1         Col1            (1,1)
Row1         Col2            (1,2)
Row1         Col3            (1,3)
Row1         Col4            (1,4)
Row1         Col5            (1,5)
Row2         Col1            (2,1)
Row2         Col2            (2,2)
...          ...             ...
RowN         ColM            (N,M)
```

And, as you might guess, I'm putting this in a cross tab in the following manner:

```
                   Columns:
                   ColumnHeader

Rows:              Summerized Fields:
RowHeader          Max of Value
```

And this generates the following report:

```
      Col1   Col2   Col3   ...  ColM
Row1  (1,1)  (1,2)  (1,3)  ...  (1,M)
Row2  (2,1)  (2,2)  (2,3)  ...  (2,M)
      ...    ...    ...    ...  ...
RowN  (N,1)  (N,2)  (N,3)  ...  (N,M)
```

Now, this report spans multiple pages and on each page, I'd like to always display the data from the first couple of rows and columns (a little like freezing panes in Excel).  The number of rows and columns that need to always be displayed is constant.  E.g. Let's say, on each page, I want columns 1 to 3 and row 1 to appear:

```
-- Page 1 --

      Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
Row1  (1,1)  (1,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)  (1,5)
Row2  (2,1)  (2,2)  (2,3)  (2,4)  (2,5)
Row3  (3,1)  (3,2)  (3,3)  (3,4)  (3,5)
Row4  (4,1)  (4,2)  (4,3)  (4,4)  (4,5)
Row5  (5,1)  (5,2)  (5,3)  (5,4)  (5,5)

-- Page 2 --

      Col1   Col2   Col3   Col6   Col7
Row1  (1,1)  (1,2)  (1,3)  (1,6)  (1,7)
Row6  (6,1)  (6,2)  (6,3)  (6,6)  (6,7)
Row7  (7,1)  (7,2)  (7,3)  (7,6)  (7,7)
Row8  (8,1)  (8,2)  (8,3)  (8,6)  (8,7)
Row9  (9,1)  (9,2)  (9,3)  (9,6)  (9,7)

-- etc. ---
```

How can I do this?

Ok ok... you caught me... I'm totally new to using Crystal Reports (what gave it away?).  I have a feeling that this cannot be done with the way the data is currently staged, but I am totally open to staging the data in another fashion to make this work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with cross-tabs.  You can achieve this by staging the data differently (i.e. in the manner it needs to be displayed) and creating a normal report.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that.. meaning your able to create a group which can which can dispatch your column.
I mean, if you column are month/year and you want only 6 per sheet.. you create a group with a formula indicating if your date in the 6st month of the year then 'start year', else 'end year'
you insert your group in the report, then you place your cross in each group... done

Answer (score 0):

Morning,

AS I say, you need to find a link between columns... I don't know how to repeat the first 3 columns, as far as they're not labels....